# DHTMLX Calendar onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml, dhtmlx

I am having an issue with the DHTMLX Calendar with the onChange in the input field.

I am initialisating the code with the following:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){              
        var calendar;
        calendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["date"]);
        calendar.hideTime();
        calendar.setDateFormat("%d/%m/%Y");
        $('.lightbox').lightbox();
        $('#slider').cycle();
    });
    function checkDate() {
        var date = $("[name='date']").val();
        alert(date);
    }
```

In the form i am using:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" onchange="checkDate();" />
```

How it should be (and was working with JQuery UI datepicker) once the date is entered into the input field the onchange function would fire. However in this case: the onchange with this calendar does nothing.

I have tried changing the following to this:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){              
        var calendar;
        calendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["date"]);
        calendar.hideTime();
        calendar.setDateFormat("%d/%m/%Y");
        calendar.attachEvent("onChange",function(date, state){
               checkDate();
        });
        $('.lightbox').lightbox();
        $('#slider').cycle();
    });
    function checkDate() {
        var date = $("[name='date']").val();
        alert(date);
    }
```

But the onchange event happens before the date is entered, ie when i click on the input field.

Reason for changing from JQuery UI to this DHTMLX is that JQuery UI Datepicker does not support all platforms (iPhones/iPads etc) and DHTMLX does.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug on the calendar when it's initialized from an input, the problem is that the onChange event is triggered once you click the input field (you can see this if you console.log or print the date argument), and not when there's a real user generated change, I had the same problem, you could alternatively  use the 'onClick' event (this will work only when they click on the selector and not when they manually change the date) or use JQUERY to catch the event since you're obtaining the date directly from the input field and not the date the calendar is sending.

```
calendar.attachEvent("onClick",function(date){
               checkDate();
        });
```